Notation $D^{m}$ in certain inequalities in $L^{p}$
In this wikipedia article, one can find the so-called "Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality, which are of the form
$${\displaystyle \|D^{j}u\|_{L^{p}(\mathbb {R} ^{n})}\leq C\|D^{m}u\|_{L^{r}(\mathbb {R} ^{n})}^{\theta }\|u\|_{L^{q}(\mathbb {R} ^{n})}^{1-\theta }}$$
for coefficients $j,m,n,p,q,r,\theta$ satisfying certain relations. I am wondering:

What does the notation $D^{m}$ for $m\in\mathbb{N}$ mean in this context?

Of course, I am very well aware of the multiindex notation $D^{\alpha}=D^{\alpha_{1}}_{1}\dots D^{\alpha_{d}}_{n}$. However, in the case above, $j$ and $m$ are just natural numbers and not multiindices. So, I am wondering, what does $D^{j}$ and $D^{m}$ mean.
The expression $D^{m}$ might be a shortcut notation for $D^{\alpha}$ for any $\alpha$ with $\vert\alpha\vert=m$, or it might also be the supremum of all those norms. Any reference or explanation is appreciated.

If you look into the original paper of Nirenberg (see here; p. 125), it is stated that $\Vert D^{l}u\Vert_{L^{p}}$ for $l\in\mathbb{N}$ is defined by
$$\Vert D^{l}u\Vert_{L^{p}}:=\max_{\vert\alpha\vert=l}\Vert D^{\alpha}u\Vert_{L^{p}}$$ and the notation $D^{l}u\in L^{p}$ means that all its derivatives $D^{\alpha}u$ for $\alpha$ with $\vert\alpha\vert=l$ are in $L^{p}$. It is actually not too hard to see that the same inequality does hold when taking instead the norm
$$||| D^{l}u|||_{L^{p}}:=\sum_{\vert\alpha\vert=l}\Vert D^{\alpha}u\Vert_{L^{p}}$$
since these two norms are equivalent. This definition of the norms is for example used in Taylor's third book on partial differential equations and his discussion of the Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequalities, e.g. see Proposition 3.5 for the inequalities and equation (2.8) on page 5 for the definition of the norms.
